# Webscraping MarineTraffic with R - rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a question on webscraping in general and a particular case. I am just starting off in my Data Analytics journey and this is my first question on Stack Overflow.

1. Can i legally scrape any website that i come across? If not then how do i determine if I can't, is it just through the website T&Cs or can i determine it when looking at the webpage code?
2. I am trying to pull in Latest Position information from the page

"https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:1914339/"

however I can;t seem to find the element when using the selector gadget.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
simple <- read_html("https://www.marinetraffic.com/uk/ais/details/ships/shipid:407535/")
simple %>% html_nodes(".css-18xv3ee") %>% html_text()
```

The response i get is

*character(0)*

Thank you for the help and looking forward to joining and contributing to this community.

Comment: First, this is not the place to ask for legal advice. There are tons of articles online about whether or not web scraping is legal but the only way to find out for sure is to wind up in court. Second, when you use selector gadget in your browser, you are generally looking at the state of a webpage after javascript has been run. Most modern pages use javascript to load data or manipulate the page after it loads. Tools like `rvest` cannot execute that same javascript. They can only see the data on the page source, not what's show in the elements tab.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. Im not looking for legal advice but your comment on "the only way to find out is to wind up in court" essentially answers my question. I understand more now on the selector gadget. How would you go about scraping data which has been loaded by javascript? Thanks for sharing

Comment: If you need to be able to scrape pages that use javascript, you can either try to reverse engineer the code to see where they are pulling data from, usually by trasking the requests on the "network" tab of the developer tools. Or you can use something like RSelenium which allows you to basically run a web browser that you can programmatically interact with. Personally I try to avoid scraping any page that doesn't have an officially supported API. Webpages often change and it's a lot of work to keep updating a scraper for frequent changes.

Comment: I will keep in mind RSelenium however i do not know javascript so reverse engineering the code would not be a possibiity. I appreciate your knowledge sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Careful to not call on it too many times, as it will block you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://www.marinetraffic.com/vesselDetails/latestPosition/shipid:407535" %>%  
  request() %>% 
  req_headers(
    referer = "https://www.marinetraffic.com/uk/ais/details/ships/shipid:407535/mmsi:351361000/imo:9399026/vessel:MSC_KALINA"
  ) %>%  
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. When i run this I get a 403 Forbidden error. Seems like it doesn't like me connecting

Comment: I get the same error when I run this code. I provided an answer based on a different approach with RSelenium.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered which is based on RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.marinetraffic.com/uk/ais/details/ships/shipid:407535/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="vesselDetails_latestPositionSection"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]')
web_Obj$getElementText()

[[1]]
[1] "Get a newer position via Satellite\nPosition Received: 2022-09-20 10:23 UTC\n58 minutes ago\nVessel's Local Time:\n2022-09-20 11:23 LT (UTC +1)\nРайон: EMED - East Mediterranean\nПоточний порт: -\nШирота / Довгота: 35.6288° / 16.4851°\nСтатус: Underway using Engine\nШвидкість / напрямок: 10.0 kn / 110 °\nAIS джерело: Wahoo_H&H (operated by Wahoo)\nNearby Vessels"
```